# Angularjs divide ng-model value and show it in textbox

Tags: angularjs

Hi I have a textbox that get a number value which it displays well but I want to convert that value by dividing it by 60.

```
 <input ng-model="customer.balance" name="" type="text" class="form-control" id="limit" placeholder="Enter limit">
```

So the customer.balance value from the database is 600 seconds but I want it to show 10 which is in minutes. When I tried the following

```
 <input ng-model="customer.balance/60" name="" type="text" class="form-control" id="limit" placeholder="Enter limit">
```

I get the non-assign error. How do I do this conversion on the html input ng-model

Comment: You may want to display it in a different text field either with ng-bind or {{}}
`divided value: {{(customer.balance/60)}}`
`<a ng-bind="customer.balance/60"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-init`

```
<input ng-model="customer.balance" ng-init="Calculation()" name="" type="text" class="form-control" id="limit" placeholder="Enter limit">
```

// in controller

```
$scope.Calculation = function()
{
customer.balance = parseInt(customer.balance)/60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two models to binding data:

```
 <input ng-model="customer.balanceTemp" ng-init="customer.balanceTemp=customer.balance/10" ng-change="customer.balance=customer.balanceTemp*10" name="" type="text" class="form-control" id="limit" placeholder="Enter limit">
```

Demo: https://codeide.co/QRgfCfOi

Comment: I checked the repo but what if I have list of customers and I want to click and see every of their balance, the temp is static which only use value of the first customer I clicked for all the customers.

Comment: You can replace `temp` variable by `customer.balanceTemp`
<input ng-model="customer.balanceTemp" ng-init="customer.balanceTemp=customer.balance/10" ng-change="customer.balance=customer.balanceTemp*10" name="" type="text" class="form-control" id="limit" placeholder="Enter limit">

Comment: The ng-init is not copying the variable for other customers except for the first one.